# For which primes $p$ does the 3rd cyclatomic polynomial $x^2+x+1$ factor over $\mathbb{F_p[x]}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, factoring

Id like some help approaching this problem please! I have found several reference to Galois theory approaches to this, but have yet to develop this in the scope of my course. Is there any other ways to go about handling this?

I really have no idea where to begin.

Comment: The roots of that polynomial are third roots of unity. The multiplicative group $\Bbb{F}_p^*$ has elements of order three iff...?

Comment: We have covered this already. Do search the site!